# Expired or revoked signing certificates with Infopath documents

Tags: certificate, infopath

Suppose I have an Infopath form that is digitally signed today by a valid, and active user.

When that user leaves the company, we disable the account and revoke the certificate. This causes a problem since the old documents that were correctly signed are reported as being invalid.

How do we maintain the integrity of a PKI infrastructure and also ensure that the valid, prior signed documents still appear as valid within Infopath?

Answer (score 0):

Where's your validation code from. In "normal" implementations, the signature date is checked against the revocation date to determine the signature integrity at the time it was created.

Did you have a look at the revocation list, what date is listed for termination of validity?

Answer (score 0):

The actual message should be that the CERTIFICATE is no longer valid. It was valid when the doc was signed and the users can still view the valid signed data. The wording is a bit confusing but the message only applies to the certificate as it is currently. It does not imply that the document was tampered with (thats a different message ;).

Unfortunately it is a matter of training/education too. There is no way to alter those messages coming out of the office products. You just have to explain what the message really means to the users - and be patient when they "forget", panic, and call you each and every time.